# sum different column value rows into a new column row in R

Tags: r

I want to combine different column value rows into a new column row.

Example df like this:

```
df <- data.frame(area = c("a","b","c","a"),
                     d = c(1,3,6,3),
                     f = c(3,2,8,2),
                     e = c(4,7,1,8),
                     g = c(6,9,2,9))
```

Where a,b,c are area column value, I want to combine/sum two rows (a,c) into one to get:

```
area  d     f   e  g
a+c+a  10  13  13  17  
b    3  2   7  9
```

AND I have tried like this:

```
df <- aggregate(df, list(area=replace(area == c("a","c"), "a+c+a")), sum)
```

But it won't work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

aggr <- df[df$area %in% c("a", "c"),-1] %>% 
  summarize_all(sum)
rbind(df[!(df$area %in% c("a", "c")),], 
      bind_cols(area = "a+c+a", aggr))

#    area    d  f  e  g
# 2     b    3  2  7  9
# 1 a+c+a   10 13 13 17
```

Comment: thanks, when I use your code on my data, the part of  "bind_cols(area = "a+c+a", aggr))" encounters an error :"cannot convert object to a data frame". and I have no ideal now

Comment: @enerstoHuang weird, when I copy/paste this exact code it works fine for me. Maybe update dplyr?